# How do you properly inherit in CSS?

Tags: css

This is my css for headers:

```
.head_red{
    background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_red.png) !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 59px;
}

.head_blue{
    background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_blue.png) !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 59px;
}

.head_green{
    background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_green.png) !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height: 59px;
}

.head_yellow{
    background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_yellow.png) !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 59px;
}

.head_orange{
    background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_orange.png) !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 59px;
}
```

What is the proper way to inherit this classes so I only have to put background-image in each?

Comment: `.head` and `.head.red`, `.head.blue`, `.head.<another color>`... So the `HTML` would be `class="head COLOR"`. Also never, I said never, use `!important`.

Comment: The question does not specify the HTML markup used, the desired appearance, or the attempted solutions. It refers to “inheritance” instead of specifying how elements should be rendered. And as so often, the question really has nothing to do with inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.head { background-repeat:no-repeat; height: 59px; }
.head_red{ background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_red.png); }
.head_blue{ background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_blue.png); }
.head_green{ background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_green.png); }
.head_yellow{ background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_yellow.png); }
.head_orange{ background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_orange.png); }
```

EXAMPLE HTML

```
<div class="head head_red">sample</div>
<div class="head head_blue">sample</div>
<div class="head head_yellow">sample</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making another class:

```
<div class="head head_green"></div>
<div class="head head_red"></div>
<div class="head head_blue"></div>
```

and..

```
.head {
    height: 59px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Then remove these styles from your current code

Answer (score 0):

Assign multiple classes:

**CSS**

```css
.head {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 59px;
}

.head--red{
    background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_red.png) !important;
}

.head--blue{
    background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_blue.png) !important;
}
/* ... */
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="head head--red"></div>
<div class="head head--blue"></div>
```

The `--` are just a naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Add another class to your head elements. For the sake of argument, let's call it `head`.

So your HTML would look a bit like this:

```
<div class='head head_red'>
            ^^^^
          new bit
```

Now you can style `.head` with the common properties and leave your background images styled as they are.

```
.head {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 59px;
}

.head_red{
    background-image: url(../../Images/box_header_red.png);
}
....etc....
```

Hope that helps.

(note: I've taken the `!important` away because you shouldn't need it; if you do need it, feel free to put it back in, but also consider trying to find out why you need it and rectifying that, because `!important` should be considered a last resort; it's not something you want to have a lot of in normal usage)